# Extract specific matching text from a string column

Tags: plsql

[The picture contains error message column(input) and err codes column (which i want the output)
I have some error codes (like 40000097,40000083 , 40000109 etc), if the error codes are there in the input text(error message) then that error code should reflect as output , if more than one error codes present then those should reflect in the output seperated by comma(,).

Please help me .. Thanks in advance ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFMbb.png)

```
    create or replace function split(i_str in varchar2) 
  return sys.odcivarchar2list pipelined is
begin
  for i in 1..length(' '||regexp_replace(i_str, '[^ ]+')) loop
    pipe row (regexp_substr(i_str, '[^ ]+', 1, i));
  end loop;
end;`
```

--using below code trying to fetch, but in the error_message if there is no space before the error_code(ie, error_message like 'lkjkkjlkjl40000097 ' then it is not identifying, if the error_message like 'lkjkkjlkjl 40000097 ') then it is identifying... please suggest me the necessary changes to be done in the below code or in the function)

```
select chk.*,Error_codes
from CHECK_ chk
join
(select CLAIM_NO,
       listagg(t2.column_value, ',') within group (order by rn, c1, c2) Error_codes
  from (select rownum rn, c1,c2,CLAIM_NO from (select CLAIM_NO,Error_Message c1,'40000109 40000083 40000098 40000101 40000076 40000097 40000088 40000081' c2 from CHECK_)) t 
    cross join table(split(c1)) t1 
   left join table(split(c2)) t2 on t2.column_value = t1.column_value
 group by rn,CLAIM_NO)ss on chk.CLAIM_NO=ss.CLAIM_NO`
```

Comment: What rule should be applied to text in "Error MSG" so that "Error code" would be extracted out of it?

Comment: I have the error codes like (40000097,40000083 , 40000109). These codes need to be compared with the error message column .If this codes are present in the error message(or matches) then that should be extracted as separate column.If all the mentioned three codes matches with error_message then all should be extracted by comma separator.

Comment: Moreover, show us please what you have done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: So, there are only these 3 error codes? Or is there a table which lists *a lot* of them? Consider creating test case for us (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data).

Comment: @Littlefoot there are around 15 error codes